# Move and rename all files in dir to date and number

Tags: bash, scripts, mv

I would like to move and rename all files in `dir` with the date and a number on the <del>end</del> front as an indicator that the files are unique. I wrote a little bash script to do this but it places the number at the front of the file name. Is this possible or do I need to go a different route?

`I am getting abc20210407215936.pdf but I would like to get the output to be something like 20210407215936-1.pdf 20210407215936-2.pdf.`

Thanks in advance. Below is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

d=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
echo "$d"

cd /path/to/pdfs

counter=1

for f in *.pdf; do
        mv -- "$f" "$d-$((counter)).pdf"
echo "files will be moved"

done


exit
```

Comment: What do you mean with "at the front"? Your code is okay. If you run it in a directory containing a file `abc.pdf` it will run a  command something like `mv -- abc.pdf abc20210407215936.pdf` as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't explain that right. I am getting abc20210407215936.pdf but I would like to get the output to be something like 20210407215936-1.pdf 20210407215936-2.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a counter and achieve it like so

```
#!/bin/bash
    
d=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)

echo "$d"
counter=0
for f in *.pdf; do
    # Since you are using mv, be very sure to check it by echoing, ow, files will be renamed
    mv -- "$f" "$d-$((++counter)).pdf"

done


exit
```

Comment: This gets the format I want but it only does it to one file and removes the rest from the directory but I don't know where they go.

Comment: Didn't you tried echoing. If not, I am afraid, the files are gone. This is the very reason I put that comment.

And it should process all pdf files in the dir you run this script in.

Try this. *Create a dir. `cd` into it. run `touch files-{1..5}.pdf`. Assuming your script is called `movers.sh`, run `./movers.sh`. Should update all files-1.pdf ... to <date-timestamp>-<counter>.pdf *

Comment: I forgot that I did have a cd to the correct dir. Also, I updated the code with what I changed. The files are test files so it doesn't matter that they're gone. The touch files command created new files. `files-1.pdf, files-2.pdf`...and so on